# Changing wordpress theme name

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to change the theme name of the currently active theme. If I deactivate the current theme and change the name in style.css and activate it back again, would this be a problem? Will I lose my widget or any other settings? I am using wordpress 3.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may lose widget settings because the theme you switch to before the renaming might not have the same sidebars registered. That's about all I'd be worried about.